# «Невозможное стало возможным: нам открылись иные миры»? ‎«Мы пойдём другим путём»?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Можно ли употреблять слово "иной"/"другой", если контекст не располагает "этим"?

> Наши собеседники начинали программу общения с дельфинами ещё в рамках
>   военных, секретных испытаний, в ходе которых выяснилось, что гораздо
>   полезнее *(чем что?)* сосуществовать с древнейшими из существ с
>   позиций взаимопомощи. Они могут помогать больным, могут
>   демонстрировать нам и открывать иные *(чем что?)* подходы и
>   возможности.

Закурсивленные вопросы в тексте - мои.

Обратно, что ли, я чипляюсь и автор меня не поймёт?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, можно и в данном случае уместно. Но кое-что другое в тексте кажется мне неудачным.

Военные "испытания" (?). Может, лучше сказать "исследования", "эксперименты"? В современном языке это не синонимы. Если бы дельфины были подготовлены, их можно было бы "испытывать" как оружие, но здесь не о том речь.

"Сосуществовать" (?). Речь идет о чем-то большем, чем сосуществование. Может быть, "общаться", "строить отношения"?

"С позиции" (?). Может быть, "на основе"?

"Древнейшие из существ" (?) Это юмор?

"Демонстрировать и открывать подходы" (?) Может, "демонстрировать возможности и открывать подходы"?

Comment: Спасибо, всё отправлю автору - пусть страдает вместо меня. )))